# Ruby On Rails - Rails Admin, navigation list items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, navigation, associations, rails-admin

Is it possible to list each items in a model in the left navigation and associated models to that record? Like this

```
Campaigns
-- campaign 1
---- quiz 1 connected to Campaign 1
------ question connected to quiz 1 
------ question connected to quiz 1
-- campaign 2
---- quiz 2 connected to Campaign 2
------ question connected to quiz 2
------ question connected to quiz 2
```

Instead of

```
Campaigns
Quiz
Questions
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to completely replace the left nav bar in Rails Admin, you can monkeypatch the `RailsAdmin::ApplicationHelper.main_navigation` helper. [See the method definition on GitHub.](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/app/helpers/rails_admin/application_helper.rb#L68)

For example, to list all the Campaigns, add this to your `config/initializers/rails_admin.rb`:

```
RailsAdmin::ApplicationHelper.module_eval do
  def main_navigation
    ("<li class=\"nav-header\">Navigation</li>" +
    "<li data-model=\"campaign\"><a class=\"pjax\" href=\"/rails_admin/campaign\">Campaigns</a></li>" +
    Campaign.all.map { |campaign|
      "<li data-model=\"campaign\"><a class=\"pjax nav-level-1\" href=\"/rails_admin/campaign/#{campaign.id}\">#{campaign.name}</a></li>"
    }.join).html_safe
  end
end
```

You can add other levels by adding more `<li>` tags containing `<a>` links with class `nav-level-2`, `nav-level-3`, etc.